# How can I authorize in the Imgur API?

Tags: angular, rest, api, authentication, imgur

I hope you can help me out with this one. I am trying to create an application and I need to upload and download images, so I decided to use the Imgur Api, however I'm having a hard time in the authorization part.

According to the documentation (https://apidocs.imgur.com/) I have to register first to get my client id and client secret, this step is done. But when I try to Authorize to get the refresh token it fails. I'm calling this URL with a get method:

```
https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MyId&response_type=token
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse 
(<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:7457:51) at 
ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:31) at Object.onInvokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36915:33) at 
ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:36) at 
Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:47) at 
ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as 
invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2818:34) at invokeTask 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:14) at 
XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback 
(http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17)
text: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Stric"
```

Pretty generic, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

By the way, I dont think is important, but my application is in Angular 5, And just in case:

```
authorize(){
  let url=`https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${this.client_id}&response_type=token`;

  console.log(url)
  this.http.get(url).subscribe((resp:any)=>{
    console.log(resp);
  });
}
```

I hope you could guide me!

Thanks!!

Comment: From the error, it says the response from API has an unexpected token '<', looks like it returns either HTML or XML.

Answer (score 0):

The response is an HTML page, so you can't parse it using any JSON parse method.

Also, the token is returned in the URL, isn't in the response.